# Marshalling SubClass Object - Properties of the Same Name

Tags: xml, groovy, jaxb

I've been trying to work out on inheritance with JAXB. For the life of mine, I can't seem to marshal an XML string from an `Employee` object. I'm expecting an XML somewhat like this:

```
<Employee>
    <Name>Max</Name>
    <ID>1199-4973-5323</ID>
</Employee>
```

The classes I use are defined below:

Person.groovy

```
@XmlRootElement(name = 'Person')
class Person {
    @XmlElement(name = 'Name')
    String name
}
```

Employee.groovy

```
@XmlRootElement(name = 'Employee')
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = '', propOrder = ['name', 'id'])
class Employee extends Person {
    @XmlElement(name = 'ID')
    String id
}
```

This throws errors:

- Regarding `Employee`'s propOrder, being that `Property name appears in
  @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists`, which is quite obvious. Are there ways I can specify the order, including fields from the parent class?
- `groovy.lang.MetaClass is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces`
- `Class has two properties of the same name "name"`

Here's the snippet of code I use for mashalling:

```
static String createXML(Object o) {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(o.getClass())
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller()

    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true)

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()
    marshaller.marshal(o, writer)
    writer.toString()
}
```

On another note, I have not tested this code. I have a bigger project here and I did this to explain my situation simpler. But from [this](https://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2012/08/jaxb-annotation-summary-crash-course.html) example, it should have been fine, right?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to delete this post, but then I thought somebody might be having the same problem as me.

I was able to resolve this by putting a `@XmlTransient` annotation in the parent class.